# Depend on the "compilation" of another file with latexmk

Tags: pdfpages, thesis, latexmk, build-system

I was given a project to build a thesis document which has a `cover.tex` and a `main.tex`.
The `cover.tex` generates the necessary covers to comply with the institution's style.
The `main.tex` file imports the pages from `cover.tex` with `\includepdf[pages=-]{cover.pdf}`.

Is there a way, using `latexmk` (which I'm already using for `makeglossaries`), to generate the cover PDF automatically when building the main document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Use `@default_files = ('cover', 'main');` in `.latexmkrc` to specify the order for generating files. Though alphabetic order is the default already.

Answer (score 2):

Just define a custom dependency to invoke latexmk to make a .pdf file (such as cover.pdf) from the corresponding .tex file:

```
add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'pdf', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );
sub makeexternaldocument {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    return system "latexmk", "-output-directory=$path", $_[0];
}
```

The only complication here was to ensure that latexmk puts the generated .pdf file is in the same directory as the .tex file, as required by the definition of a custom dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a build automation tool such as GNU Make. A simple `Makefile` can look like

```
all: main.pdf

main.pdf: cover.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    latexmk -pdf $<

clean:
    latexmk -CA
```

Using the command `make` we build `cover.pdf` if needed and then `main.pdf`, each using the [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) `%.pdf: %.tex` to build the file using `latexmk`.